# MIssing setting to go back to traditional mouse scroll

Tags: macos, mouse, settings

With OSX Lion, scroll directions have been reversed and I'm looking to get back to the old behavior. On my laptop there is a setting in System Preferences under Mouse to get it back to the way it was.

On my desktop this setting is missing!

Is there another way I can get it so that the scrolling is back to the way it was on all computers pre-Lion?

Comment: I am also searching for this setting in my macbook pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the issue.

I have the IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0 and the option did not show up under the Mouse settings. So what I've done was connect my Logitech mouse and clicked the setting to revert the scroll directions.

Now when I connect my IntelliMouse, I get the desired scroll directions. Kind of annoying that I had to use a *different* mouse to get the setting but at least its scrolling in the same direction.

Answer (score 2):

### Mouse:

System Preferences +> Mouse =>
Uncheck “Move content in the direction of finger movement when scrolling or navigating”

### Trackpad:

System Preferences => Trackpad => Scroll & Zoom.
Uncheck “Scroll direction: natural”

<sup>It seems depending on your hardware, the Preferences Panel changes. The magic-mouse has different settings then a normal mouse. This is for the settings panel with the mighty-mouse. Your mileage may vary.</sup>